# Error while deploying on device in Xamarin.Android after upgrade to AndroidX in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat, visual-studio-2019, androidx

I recently updated Xamarin Android project to support AndroidX. I migrated `PreferenceManager` and few mandatory APIs/methods like `ExternalStorageDirectory`, `SetColorFilter` only, to have successful compilation.

As, there are few third party libraries, which are still using old v4/v7 support libraries. Meaning, I can not start migration of support libraries.

With this, build is working fine. I can deploy to device and run the app.
But, While deploying to device in debug mode, getting below error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       MSB4018: The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.<GetTypeAndBaseTypes>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition type, String typeName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.AddJavaTypes(List`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinition type)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, IAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()         0
```

Did someone also, found this issue?

Same question already asked:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/169837/vs-2019-gives-error-could-not-load-assembly-xamarin-android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: @vlTs, can you try to update Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat and try again?

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT, Already updated Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat to 28.0.0.3. Which is I guess, lasted and last update available. I am using "Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" package for building.

Comment: It doesn't seem right, search you entire solution for use cases of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`. You shouldn't need `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7` for `AppCompat`, since it just uses `AndroidX.AppCompat.App` & `AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget` now.
Check this sample too https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinAndroidXMigration/tree/master/samples/AndroidXOnlyApp/AndroidXOnlyApp & also check your ProGuard/Shrinker

Comment: I tried to remove references of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`, but its used in third party libraries. Can't be removed directly.
I am keeping all older support libraries, as suggested in `Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration` ReadMe.

Comment: @vITs  Did you solved it? I am facing similar issue

Comment: I tried with latest migration nuget recently. No issues I faced.